# If I add a column to my view, will it also add column in my base table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2019

I have a base/raw table without any ID or column with unique values, so I want to add a new column to my view with unique value like an ID.

If I add new column to my view, will it also add it to my base table?

If yes, then how to avoid that means add column only in view without affecting base table.

Comment: No, adding a computed column in a view should have no effect on the structure of the underlying table.  If you were using a materialized view, there would be a storage penalty.

Comment: Sounds like you should really be modifying your base table to give it a primary key.

Comment: A view definition has no effect on the schema of any base table it references (which can be 0 or more), it's just a query definition (also manifested as a separate copy of the data if materialized)

Comment: `VIEWS` are a completely separate objects. You could almost think of them more like pre-written `SELECT` statements that you can then call (they're more than this, but it's a simiplified explanation); they can have `JOIN`s, CTEs, `WHERE`s, aggregation, etc. What would you expect to occur if you had a query with `JOIN`s and you added a column to its `SELECT`? What table would that column be added to?